# multiple control files to restore in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, backup, restore, rman

I should restore oracle backup to my host,  I have three control files as you can see blow :

c-1295819063-20170920-00

c-1295819063-20170920-01

c-1295819063-20170920-02

I will be pleased if you could help me to select correct control file to restore?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know which control files to use based on the file name alone. Chances are that the control 1295819063-20170920-0x files are multiplexed, meaning that 00, 01, and 02 might be copies of the same file.

I would encourage you to do more research about control files and how backups/restores should be handled before selecting a control file to use for your recovery.

More information about control files:

> https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/managing-control-files.htm#ADMIN006

More information on recovery scenarios, including control files:

> https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/BRADV/rman-recovery-advanced.htm#BRADV008